# extracting certain files from a tar and putting them in another one

Tags: python, tarfile

I've got a tar file, `tar1.tar`, and I want to look at the files inside them and put all the files which pass `my_test` into another tar, `output.tar`.

I've been doing this but I can't open the file in my new tar:

```
import tarfile
tar = open("tar1.tar")
passing_members = []
for member in tar.getmembers():
    my_file = tar.extractfile(member)
    if my_test(my_file.read()):
        passing_members.append(member)

output_tar = tarfile.open("output.tar", "w|")
for member in passing_members:
    output_tar.addfile(member)

output_tar.close()
tar.close()
```

I don't really understand what the members are, I think I need to be adding something like member.extractfile() instead of member but I can't get it to work.

I have managed to get it to work on test files by extracting everything but it would take too long for the proper files.

In fact I've got lots of tar files that I want to extract all the files which pass a test from but if I can do it for one I can loop.

I'm using python 2.7

Comment: Did you try `passing_members.append(my_file)`?

Comment: Yes, I get `AttributeError: 'ExFileObject' object has no attribute 'tobuf'`